# undefined method in users login test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I've just finished the chapter 8 of https://www.railstutorial.org/book/basic_login and the site is online (check here: https://peaceful-river-79951.herokuapp.com/). The only problem is in the final test:

```
test "login with valid information followed by logout" do
  get login_path
  post login_path, params: { session: { email:    @user.email,
                                        password: 'password' } }
  assert is_logged_in?
  assert_redirected_to @user
  follow_redirect!
  assert_template 'users/show'
  assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
  assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
  assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
  delete logout_path
  assert_not is_logged_in?
  assert_redirected_to root_url
  follow_redirect!
  assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path
  assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path,      count: 0
  assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user), count: 0
end
```

Error:
UsersLoginTest#test_login_with_valid_information_followed_by_logout:
NoMethodError: undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
    test/integration/users_login_test.rb:17:in`block in '

As I understand, it's more a problem with the @user than with the email method.
@user is not supposed to be nil for the test to be successful. How can I solve this ?

Everything is on Github here: https://github.com/kart-able/sample_app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `setup` task, see Listing 8.23 in https://www.railstutorial.org/book/basic_login, which reads

```
 def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
 end
```

Comment: Thanks! No comment ;)